# Praat - can't open some wav files, "file not finished" error

Tags: praat

I'm making a web app which records some audio on the frontend, and then processes it using Praat on the backend. However I'm running into an inconsistent error where the .wav audio files can't be opened by Praat, accompanied by a number of error messages. The audio files are fine, and can be played using an recording software. However, when trying to open from file in the Praat ui (or from script) a variety of the following errors ensue:

e.g:

File "path" not recognized.
File "path" not finished.

Ignored 116 null bytes in text file "path".
Row 1 incomplete.
Table object not read from character-separated text file "path".
File "path" not finished.

The file path is correct, and the audio file plays correctly in another software. The file is the correct format (.wav). Sometimes the audio files process correctly and are analysed successfully, however other times these errors occur.